# How do fare restrictions work in case of rebooking?

Tags: airlines, fares

I have a fare class with the restrictions as the following:

> > THE FARE COMPONENT MUST BE ON ONE OR MORE OF THE FOLLOWING

> ANY AZ FLIGHT OPERATED BY AZ.

I was thinking to myself, are the fare restrictions still applicable in case of rebooking, due to a cancellation for example?

In this example, the fare is for a connecting itinerary on the same airline, but there is another flight a bit later, on an alliance airline that is direct and wouldn't delay the arrival at all (the fare routing rules would allow such direct flight).

Assuming available seats, green light from the other airline, and in case of cancellation, would the fare restrictions still need to apply (forcing rebooking on the next AZ flight) or would they be able to rebook on the alliance airline flight?

---

**Note :**

- I am not asking if they would do it, I am asking if it is possible for them, according to the fare restrictions, to rebook on a different airline

Comment: It's at their discretion if they rebook you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is certainly possible. The fare restrictions are simply a coded field in the ticket stating what is allowed under normal operations. In a rebooking situation (i.e. canceled flight, etc) the agents have a lot more latitude in rebooking. In the US, for example, you won't find Delta selling fares on American or United, but they certainly can and do put passengers on them in extreme situations. In other words, the fare restrictions do not impose any sort of technical limitation that would block an airline from reaccommodating you on another carrier that's not listed.

The same goes for the other fare rules as well.